# invalid password at my Cisco 2961 router

Tags: cisco, router, ios

I am going crazy here! I set a password at my router and I can't think of anything that could be wrong! I even saved the configuration before I got locked out of the router, I will share it with you. I know how to do password recovery, but I am just wondering what is wrong with the commands I entered earlier! Am I missing something? please let me know

Start of my mess up!

```
amm-router>
amm-router>
amm-router>en
amm-router#ccof t
            ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

amm-router#conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
amm-router(config)#line console 0
amm-router(config-line)#ogin
                        ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

amm-router(config-line)#login
% Login disabled on line 0, until 'password' is set
amm-router(config-line)#password
% Incomplete command.

amm-router(config-line)#password ae7admin
amm-router(config-line)#^Z
amm-router#
*Dec 25 18:16:26.490: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console
amm-router#exit

































amm-router con0 is now available





Press RETURN to get started.















User Access Verification

Password:
amm-router>en
amm-router#

































amm-router con0 is now available





Press RETURN to get started.



User Access Verification

Password:
amm-router>
amm-router>
amm-router>
amm-router>
amm-router>
amm-router>
amm-router>conf t
              ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

amm-router>conf t
              ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

amm-router>en
amm-router#conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
amm-router(config)#line console 0
amm-router(config-line)#no password
amm-router(config-line)#end
amm-router#
*Dec 26 00:39:36.084: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console
amm-router#copy run start
Destination filename [startup-config]?
Building configuration...
[OK]
amm-router#log out
               ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

amm-router#end
Translating "end"...domain server (192.168.1.1)
 (192.168.1.1)
Translating "end"...domain server (192.168.1.1)

% Bad IP address or host name
% Unknown command or computer name, or unable to find computer address
amm-router#^Z
amm-router#exit

































amm-router con0 is now available





Press RETURN to get started.







amm-router>
amm-router>
amm-router>en
amm-router#
amm-router#
amm-router#line console 0
             ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

amm-router#conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
amm-router(config)#line console 0
amm-router(config-line)#login
% Login disabled on line 0, until 'password' is set
amm-router(config-line)#login ?
  local  Local password checking
  <cr>

amm-router(config-line)#login local
amm-router(config-line)#username
amm-router(config-line)#username ae7admin secret password
amm-router(config-line)#username ae7admin secret password ae7admin
amm-router(config)#
amm-router(config)#end
amm-router#ena
*Dec 26 00:41:36.044: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console
amm-router#enable secret ae7admin
                  ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

amm-router#enable secret ae7admin
amm-router#conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
amm-router(config)#enable s
amm-router(config)#enable secret ae7admin
amm-router(config)#line vty 0 15
amm-router(config-line)#login local
amm-router(config-line)#user
amm-router(config-line)#username ae7admin secret password ae7admin
amm-router(config)#
amm-router(config)#
amm-router(config)#
amm-router(config)#^Z
amm-router#
amm-router#
amm-router#
*Dec 26 00:43:29.832: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console
amm-router#show run
amm-router#show running-config
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1589 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 00:43:29 UTC Sat Dec 26 2015
version 15.2
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname amm-router
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
enable secret 4 QwLCYWKCJNIfpMMUinHjBoG0qjxCQ2DhbtSFKwMz6QY
!
no aaa new-model
memory-size iomem 15
!
ip cef
!
!
!
!


!
!
!
!
no ipv6 cef
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2921/K9 sn FTX1727AHSX
license accept end user agreement
license boot module c2900 technology-package datak9
!
!
username ae7admin secret 4 aSQEuYE5xWNSUVzXBzAulkBYFjwogPRPhZpiyofmfP2
!
redundancy
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Embedded-Service-Engine0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address dhcp
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet0/0
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 60 0
 logging synchronous
 login local
 history size 100
line aux 0
line 2
 no activation-character
 no exec
 transport preferred none
 transport output lat pad telnet rlogin lapb-ta mop udptn v120 ssh
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 exec-timeout 60 0
 logging synchronous
 login local
 history size 100
 transport input all
line vty 5 15
 exec-timeout 60 0
 logging synchronous
 login local
 history size 100
 transport input all
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
!
end

amm-router#
amm-router#
amm-router#copy run st
amm-router#copy run startup-config
Destination filename [startup-config]?
Building configuration...
[OK]
amm-router#
amm-router#
amm-router#
amm-router#exit

































amm-router con0 is now available





Press RETURN to get started.










User Access Verification

Username: ae7admin
Password:
% Login invalid

Username: ae7admin
Password:
% Login invalid

Username:
% Username:  timeout expired!

































amm-router con0 is now available





Press RETURN to get started.












User Access Verification

Username: ae7admin
Password:
% Login invalid

Username: ae7admin
Password:
% Login invalid

Username:
% Username:  timeout expired!

































amm-router con0 is now available





Press RETURN to get started.









User Access Verification

Username: ae7admin
Password:
% Login invalid

Username: ae7admin secret
Password:
% Login invalid

Username:
% Username:  timeout expired!

































amm-router con0 is now available





Press RETURN to get started.
```

Answer (score 1):

**Cause:** You were attempting to login before you had added the password.

To add a password to line console 0

`router> en`

`router# config t`

`router(config)# line console 0`

`router(config)# password (yourpassword)`

`router(config)# login`